# How to get Latitude Longitude from SQL Server 2008 geography line?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, mapping

I'm new to the mapping world and I'm trying to convert a SQL Server geography line column back into it's latitude \ longitude points to draw on a map.

The line is being set like this

```
Set @GeoPoly = geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING('+@Polyline+')',4326)
```

Anyone know how to do this?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had luck with this:

```
DECLARE @g geography;
SET @g = geography::STLineFromText(
   'LINESTRING(-122.360 47.656, -122.343 47.656 )'
    , 4326
); 
SELECT @g.STPointN(1).ToString(), @g.STPointN(2).ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Does your LineString consist of only one straight line segment connecting two points? If so, you can retrieve the latitude and longitude of those points as:

```
SELECT
  @GeoPoly.STStartPoint.Lat AS Start_Lat,
  @GeoPoly.STStartPoint.Long AS Start_Long,
  @GeoPoly.STEndPoint.Lat AS End_Lat,
  @GeoPoly.STEndPoint.Long AS End_Long;
```

If your LineString consists of multiple line segments connecting a series of points then you can retrieve the Well-Known Text representation using the ToString() method, and then parse the resulting string into coordinate pairs by splitting on commas:

```
SELECT @GeoPoly.ToString()
```

The result will be in the format: LINESTRING(Lon1 Lat1, Lon2, Lat2, ....  , Lonn, Latn)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in a query by combining STasText(), STRING_SPLIT(), CROSS APPLY and STRING_AGG(). Here is an example query:

```
WITH Links AS (
    SELECT Id, REPLACE(REPLACE(PosList.STAsText(), 'LINESTRING (', ''), ')', '') as points_string
    FROM LinkSequenceProjections
    WHERE ImportFileId = 1
    AND Id < 5
)
, Points AS (
    SELECT Id, ltrim(value) as point_string, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER By Id) as Nr
    FROM Links
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(points_string, ',')
)
, Coords AS (
    SELECT Id, Nr, CAST(value AS [varchar](max)) AS coord
    FROM Points
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(point_string, ' ')
)
, GroupedByNr AS (
    SELECT Id, Nr, MIN(coord) AS Lon, MAX(coord) AS Lat
    FROM Coords
    GROUP BY Id, Nr
)
, GroupedById AS (
    SELECT Id, 'LINSESTRING (' + STRING_AGG(Lon + ' ' + Lat, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Nr) + ')' as wkt2
    FROM GroupedByNr
    GROUP BY Id
)
SELECT Id, geography::STGeomFromText(wkt2, 4326) AS PosList2
FROM GroupedById
```